# How to create a chart that has two data sets using Excel VBA 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is really two separate questions. First, I have an excel sheet with three columns of data. I have 12 rows of data in columns A, C, and E. From what I've been looking up, This program should assign column A to the x-axis, and Columns C and D to the y-axis, while also adding labels.

```
Sub ChartMaker()
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:A12,C1:C12,E1:E12")
        .Location xlLocationAsNewSheet
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL Over Time"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Days)"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL"
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .HasLegend = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I keep getting the error "Object variable or With block variable not set".

That's my first question!

My second question is how can I create a graph with the following sets of data, where there are two sets of data on the y-axis, but  they share an x-axis.

Data set one:

```
X     Y1

1    0.87
2    0.45
3    0.92
4    0.03
5    0.99
6    0.45
7    0.63
8    0.83
9    0.28
10   0.66
```

Data set two:

```
X      Y2

0.3    2
4.5    3
6      6
7.2    1
7.8    6
8.3    1 
9.1    4
9.6    5
10     9
13     2
```

Is there a way to get these on the same graph? (Using VBA of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating the chart

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select  
'this adds the chart and selects it in the same statement
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
```

you then add the first set of points

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$C$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$3:$A$12"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$C$3:$C$12"
```

and use the same method to add the second set

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Sheet1!$E$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Sheet1!$D$3:$D$12"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$E$3:$E$12"
```

Comment: Does the first part add the chart? Or do I also need `ActiveWorkBook.Charts.Add` for the first line?

Comment: the first line creates the chart, and also makes it active, all in a single statement

Comment: Thank you! I have a few other questions if you don't mind. First, when this creates the graph, for some reason on the legend it has three different series listed. Why is this third one being created? I have exactly what you have up there, just changed to fit my ranges. Lastly, how do I change the marker type/size/color for the different series?

Comment: I should also add, how do I make the chart fill a specific area? For example, if I want it to resize and move to fit the area from J1 to S7?

Comment: .Left, .top, .Width, .Height (all measured in points) or, if you want it on it's own sheet, `ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet`